# trim URLs after third level

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I need to trim URLs after the third `/` . I removed the *http* from the beginning to make it easier.

Example:

```
a.ssl.fastly.net/static/r07/auth014.js
0.tqn.com/f/f/a/a.ttf?v=3.0.1
```

This should return

```
a.ssl.fastly.net/static/r07
0.tqn.com/f/f
```

I tried

```
echo "0.tqn.com/f/f/a/a.ttf?v=3.0.1" | sed 's/.*[\/].*[\/].*[\/].*/\1/'
```

but it does not seem to work and throws an error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/` as separator and print using awk:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `cut`:

```
cut -d/ -f1-3
```

Example:

```
$ echo "0.tqn.com/f/f/a/a.ttf?v=3.0.1" | cut -d/ -f1-3
0.tqn.com/f/f
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|/[^/]*||3g' file
```

Using a `|` as a delimiter for the substitute command, delete a `/` followed by any number of non-`/`'s from the 3rd occurance to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This removes last field:

```
awk -F/ '{$NF=""}1' OFS=/
a.ssl.fastly.net/static/r07/
0.tqn.com/f/f/a/
```